# Python error trying to use .execute() SQLite API query With keyword arguments

Tags: python, database, sqlite, execute

I'm learning SQLite and have been trying to create a string that stores values and retrieves rows, but I get an error "execute() takes no keyword arguments." This is the way I referenced the database:

```
import sqlite3
dbb = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
db = dbb.cursor()
username = request.form.get("username")

#query database for username
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", \ 
username=username)
```

UPDATE

I misrepresented my parameters. I used the qmarks notation mentioned in the accepted answer below to reference table rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) says:

> The `sqlite3` module supports two kinds of placeholders: question marks (qmark style) and named placeholders (named style).
>
> Here’s an example of both styles:
>
> ```py
> # This is the qmark style:
> cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))
>
> # And this is the named style:
> cur.execute("select * from people where name_last=:who and age=:age", {"who": who, "age": age})
> ```

Keyword arguments are not supported. However, you could explicitly convert them into a dictionary (or write a wrapper for `execute` that does this):

```py
db.execute("SELECT ... :username", dict(username = username))
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that bit. The qmark style works perfectly for a method of templating I hadn't yet considered.